# Frequent Internet Disconnection

Tags: cisco, switch, firewall, internet, networking

---

Hello everyone!

---

I am relatively new to this forum, and wanted to get some useful feedbacks and resolution from "**network-PROs**" on my problem..

I have a network with a main router connected to the Fortigate Firewall 100E, that is connected to a **Cisco SG300-28PP 28-Port Gigabit PoE+ Managed Switch** through which all the user computers and IP phones are connected.

Lately, time-to-time, out of no-where, the internet keeps disconnecting. From the LAN, I'm unable to access the firewall and its unreachable. The WiFi from the main router works fine, that means the Internet is okay.
After restarting the firewall physically, everything is back to normal and the internet runs fine..
I have checked the switch, and it shows no sign of problem in any way!

I don't know if its the problem of the firewall or the switch. Hope someone can guide me to the right direction.

[image: Logs from the Fortinet]

That **power supply lost** is from the time, when I had to restart the Firewall from the switch, since it was inaccessible.

*P.S: I have been seeing this logs about Link-up and Link-down for the WAN.. The same problem hasn't happened yet. I have also restarted the CISCO Switch couple of days back, since then, there is no problem.*

Comment: Both the firewall and the switch have logging features.  Look at the logs of both devices for some clues as to what's wrong.   I'm most suspicious of the firewall.

Comment: If you can't reach the firewall it's not the Internet uplink that's failing...

Comment: when this occurs, is there any port flap on the switch? Is it possible to send equipment logs? The firewall you have access to it remotely to verify when this problem happens, if the firewall still has internet? if it works, you can already eliminate it and focus on the switch.
I await logs

Comment: @RonTrunk I have posted below the screenshot of the Fortinet log.. As for the Cisco Switch, its totally blank.. or maybe I'm checking in the wrong place..

Comment: @PedroFerreira - I'm unsure of the concept **'port flap'**.. The firewall is inaccessible when this problem happens, even if you connect to the LAN of the firewall..